# ESD Clamping diode specification

Tags: voltage, current, diodes, esd, tvs

I'm using this [Ethernet PHY](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/8720a.pdf)

I've connected the ESD diodes on the Ethernet differential signal lines.

When I use this [part](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/916/PESD3V3Y1BSF-1370637.pdf) the device is failing ESD.
When I use this [part](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpd1e1b04.pdf?ts=1675664193510&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) the device works fine.

Can someone tell me what is the reason for this?

Comment: Why is an Ethernet PHY subject to ESD ?

Comment: Not specifically ESD. But a 0.5kV transient

Comment: Where is this diode, how is it connected, and how is the "ESD" test performed on it? Schematics? PCB layouy? I mean, it is impossible to use an HV generator directly on the PHY pins anyway. So as it is, the question can't be answered.

Comment: I meant, that it is isolated. So peripheral common-mode transients don't affect it, usually.

Comment: I would like to know the difference between the two diodes? Why it works with one and fails with another?

Comment: That depends on how it is used in the circuit. Both will handle "ESD" fine. And both make no sense in an Ethernet context IMO. So please add details that @Justme asked or there cant even be an educated guess.

Comment: If you want an uneducated guess regardless: I think the transients they experience in your test are not typical 61000-4-2 types they are rated for, so they are used outside of their specs. One diode copes with it better than the other. The 1 pF diode is probably a little beefier.

Comment: Is there any difference with respect to the performance based on the clamping voltages relating to ethernet whose working voltage is 3.3V? Because the NXP parts clamping voltage is 2.5V - Hence it fails because it doesn't clamp to 3.3V during surge right? hence we observe the failure with that part.

Comment: Is my above understanding right?

Comment: Or can someone educate me on what would be the right clamping voltage that should be placed on the differential lines on the above IC?

Comment: @Newbie The differences in the parts or what clamping voltages should be used are irrelevant until we know where and how they are connected in the circuit. You need to show the schematics of ESD clamps and their relation to connector, magnetics, PHY, ground plane, etc. And where do you apply the pulse, to Ethernet connector pin, to metal case, connector shield, or to supply pins, etc.

Comment: You did the tests, where are the measurements? Even with a quick glance at he datasheets, it’s pretty clear the TI part is more robust. It also has more capacitance and a 30kV rating vs 15kV. One would think the lower clamping voltage would be better, but you have no evidence to tell what is really happening. I’d suspect the clamping voltage is much higher than 2.5V, thus the failure. Make your measurements and be guided by the data. Otherwise it’s all conjecture. For all we know, adding 20pF capacitors might work as well.